# Key Error in Flask Sessions

Tags: python, session, flask

So I have been using sessions to pass data from one decorator to another. But now every time I make a new session variable, I get a KeyError from page to page. Meaning, I had a session error from my third to fourth page; but I had the same issue adding a new session variable from my second to third page even though I have four other session variables that give me no error.

My code is similar to the one @laila posted below:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask import request, session, url_for,abort,redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'


@app.route('/'):
def first():
    session['this_one']='hello'
    render('template.html')

@app.route('/second')
def second():
   it=session['this_one']
    render('other_page.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Aren't you missing the part of "load the configuration of choice and then create the Session object by passing it the application."? https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session

Answer (score -1):

it seems like the code has some syntax error.Please try the code below, it should be ok:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask import request, session, url_for, abort, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'


@app.route('/')
def first():
    session['this_one'] = 'hello'
    return render_template('template.html')


@app.route('/second')
def second():
    it = session.get('this_one', 'not found')
    return render_template('other_page.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```